# Rcpp (Eigen), duplicate or repeat rows

Tags: r, eigen, rcpp

I was wondering if there’s a method in Rcpp, c++ or Eigen to duplicate or repeat each row of a given matrix n times?

For example, if I have a 2 x 2 matrix...:

```
(1,2
 3,4)
```

...to turn it into a 4 x 2 matrix like:

```
(1,2
 1,2
 3,4
 3,4)
```

I did not find any method or question like this on stackoverflow or anywhere in the docs of Eigen or Rcpp.

I’m aware, that I could use a for loop or an R-function from within Rcpp, but I’m worried, that this would cost a lot of performance.

Can anyone provide a hint on how to do this?

EDIT: This seems like an easy case for R, but it does not work with large matrices that cause memory to exceed. I am passing the data to a compiled Rcpp function anyway, so I would like to do it in there.

Regards
Tim

Comment: I can't say much about the R part, but generally (especially for Eigen) you need to decide whether you actually want to store the repeated matrix or just have an "(almost) zero cost" lazy expression (this really depends on what you intend to do with that matrix).

Comment: Keep in mind that R and Eigen and many others system in general have the same memory model where a vector (and a matrix, seen as a vector with 2-d dimension) have continuous memory. So you always have the same memory issue.

Comment: Thank you for that remark, Dirk! So the safest way in terms of memory would be Allans approach from below?

Comment: Thanks @chtz. Can you elaborate how I could use such a lazy expression?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably don't need Rcpp or Eigen for this. The following is vectorized natively in R and doesn't require loops, so it should be quick enough.

```r
mat[rep(seq(nrow(mat)), each = 2),]
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    2
#> [2,]    1    2
#> [3,]    3    4
#> [4,]    3    4
```

You may get a bit of a performance boost from writing an equivalent in C++, but I would be surprised if it made a huge difference. If in doubt you could always profile.

If you want an Rcpp function that does the same thing, then you could try:

```r
Rcpp::cppFunction("NumericMatrix double_matrix(NumericMatrix m) {
   int nrow = 2 * m.rows();
   NumericMatrix res(nrow, m.ncol());
   for(int i = 0; i < nrow; ++i){
     res(i, _) = m((int) i / 2, _);
   }
   return res;
}")
```

So you can do:

```r
double_matrix(mat)
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    2
#> [2,]    1    2
#> [3,]    3    4
#> [4,]    3    4
```

---

**Data**

```r
mat <- matrix(c(1, 3, 2, 4), ncol = 2)

mat
#>      [,1] [,2]
#> [1,]    1    2
#> [2,]    3    4
```

Comment: Thank you, Allen!

The problem is memory. I’m dealing with large matrices, so any approach in R continuously exceeds my RAM. I am passing the data to a compiled Rcpp-function anyway, so I would like to do it in there before I’m performing the matrix operations with Eigen.

Comment: @timbo1988 see my update. The Rcpp function is pretty straightforward anyway. It includes a loop of course (but the loop has to exist at some level). You may find it is quicker if you iterate on columns rather than rows.

Comment: Wow, thank you Allen! I’m generally trying to avoid for loops, but as they are much quicker in c++, I will give it a try!

Comment: Hi, hate to bug you but what does ```(int) i / 2``` do?  I do not know what to google to find the answer. +1 and thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `kronecker` is an option for you when with base R

```
> kronecker(mat, rep(1, 2))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    2
[2,]    1    2
[3,]    3    4
[4,]    3    4
```

Comment: Nice one! Never knew about that function.